# How to add iterator to each line using awk, sed or grep?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

How would I use grep, sed or awk to insert an iterator to each line (row), the length of the file?

Say my data looks like this, in csv format:

```
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
.
.
.
1,2,3,4
```

I want to make it look like this, using grep, awk or sed (or whatever else works):

```
[func (func (func 0)) [1 2 3 4]]
[func (func (func 1)) [1 2 3 4]]
[func (func (func 2)) [1 2 3 4]]
.
.
.
[func (func (func N)) [1 2 3 4]]
```

Where `N` is the number of rows in the file. So basically inserting the line number, of the file, into the line itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` and the `NR` variable.

Something like this:

```
awk '{ gsub(/,/, " "); print "[func (func (func "(NR-1)")) ["$0"]]"; }' datafile
```

Answer (score 3):

In pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
while IFS=, read -r a1 a2 a3 a4; do
    echo "[func (func (func $((c++)))) [$a1 $a2 $a3 $a4]]"
done < file
```

Comment: I like pure `bash` solutions +1.

Comment: You can also improv it to support any number of values, with arrays:   `while IFS=, read -ra array; do echo "[func (func (func $((c++)))) [${array[@]}]]"; done < file`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed = file | sed 'N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/[func (func (func \1)) [\2]/'
```

This inserts the line number into the output stream (Stdout) and then uses a second invocation of sed to pair it to its line and output the required string.